# Script component with WCF Invalid contract attribute in app.config

Tags: c#, wcf, ssis

I'm trying to configure a script component with a service reference to my WSDL file inside this boiler plate method.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
       //create instance of service client 

    }
```

However I'm running into problems with the configuration file app.config which is complaining about an invalid contract attribute `contract="ServiceReference1.IClientService1`
All attempts to change this manually have failed. Similar posts suggest using a fully qualified name Service.MyService but I'm not having any success so far. Is there a way to specify the binding programmatically?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IClientService1">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IClientService11" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://server/services/ClientService1.svc/soap"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IClientService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IClientService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IClientService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Stub code looks like following

```
 public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        string endpoint = "https://server/services/ClientService1.svc";
        ClientService1Client client = new ClientService1Client(endpoint);
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "";
        Output0Buffer.name = client.GetActiveClients()[1].name.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Could not find endpoint element with name 'https:/server/ClientService1.svc/soap' and contract 'ServiceReference1.IClientService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.

Comment: Is ServiceReference1 the namespace the IClientService1 contract is under?

Comment: @Popo yes, it's the name of the ServiceReference I added so it can be changed

Comment: the endpoint address cannot be `https:/server/ClientService1.svc/soap` it should just be `https:/server/ClientService1.svc` also you are able to programmatically create your binding and endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue may be due to having `/soap` in your endpoint address

```
<endpoint address="https://server/services/ClientService1.svc/soap"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IClientService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IClientService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IClientService1" />
```

I think it should just be:

```
address="https://server/services/ClientService1.svc"
```

As for creating the binding programmatically this should work or get you started:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://server/services/ClientService1.svc");
ClientService1Client client = new ClientService1Client(binding, address);
```