# Using WF to make call to Soap Service over HTTPS

Tags: wcf, ssis, soap-client

I've tested the endpoint against Postman, it does exist despite what visual studio is claiming. There's errors in the app.config file when I add the service reference so I decided to configure the binding and endpoint manually in code.

Script task:

```
public void Main()
    {

        //configure WCF manually , endpoint, HTTPS binding, etc
        BasicHttpsBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://service/services/Operation.svc");
        ST_364d1c14d92b406e87f51c75a462f403.ClientServiceRef.ClientService1Client client = new ClientService1Client(binding, address);
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "";

        //make call to SOAP service using client instance
        var column_names = client.GetAllClients();
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Runtime error - doesn't seem to recognize endpoint

```
 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

For reference here's the app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IClientService1">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IClientService11" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https:/server.com/services/ClientService1.svc/soap"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IClientService1"
                contract="ClientServiceRef.IClientService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IClientService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: For more information refer to my related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44051012/script-component-with-wcf-invalid-contract-attribute-in-app-config

Comment: Is it throwing that exception when it does `client.GetAllClients();` or when it does `Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;` ? that error does not look related to not finding an endpoint.

Comment: @Popo when it does client.GetAllClients() - there also seems to be a bug in SSIS where changes to the script component aren't being saved.

Comment: do you have a the code that is executed by the service when calling `client.GetAllClients();` wrapped in a try catch block? That error really looks like an error with a SSIS script task not the web service call. Maybe I am missing something here though.